# Java Spring: unit test failing with IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

Working on a Java Spring application, and created an `MLController` class and corresponding `@Bean`.  I declared the Bean in the same way as every other one, however the unit test `contextLoads()` is preventing the app from building.

I deleted everything but the simplest function in my class, but it still fails!  I know this Bean is causing the problem, as it builds when I delete it.  What could be the problem?

#### Error

```
live.cibc.labs.springbackend.SpringbackendApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

#### MLController Class

```
@RestController
public class MLController {

    MLService mlService;

    public void setMlService(MLService service) {
        this.mlService = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/testindex")
    public String index() {
        return String.valueOf("BRUH");
    }
}
```

#### Application.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
@SpringBootApplication

public class SpringbackendApplication {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbackendApplication.class, args);
        FirebaseUtil.initializeFirebase();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        if (System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT") != null && System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT").equals("production")) {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + this.env.getProperty("POSTGRES_PROD_URL"));
        } else {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + this.env.getProperty("POSTGRES_DEV_URL"));
        }

        dataSource.setUsername(this.env.getProperty("POSTGRES_USER"));
        dataSource.setPassword(this.env.getProperty("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserController userController() {
        UserController userController = new UserController(getUserDAO(), getYodleeDAO());
        userController.setCobrandSession(cobrandSession());
        userController.setUserSessionManager(userSessionManager());
        userController.setAccountsService(accountsService());
        userController.setTransactionsService(transactionsService());
        return userController;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestController testController() {
        TestController testController = new TestController();
        testController.setCobrandSession(cobrandSession());
        testController.setUserSessionManager(userSessionManager());
        testController.setAccountsService(accountsService());
        testController.setTransactionsService(transactionsService());
        return testController;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountsService accountsService() {
        AccountsService accountsService = new AccountsService();
        accountsService.setApiBase(this.env.getProperty("YODLEE_API_BASE"));
        accountsService.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
        accountsService.setGson(gson());
        return accountsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionsService transactionsService() {
        TransactionsService transactionsService = new TransactionsService();
        transactionsService.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
        transactionsService.setGson(gson());
        return transactionsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public MLService mlService() {
        MLService service = new MLService();
        service.setRestTemplate(restTemplate());
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    public MLController mlController() {
        MLController controller = new MLController();
        controller.setMlService(new MLService());
        return controller;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setOutputStreaming(false); // If we don't turn this off, we may get HttpRetryException on 401's.
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public Gson gson() {
        return new Gson();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the `mlController()` method take an `MLService` argument? Don't you want the controller to have the service from the `mlService()` method to be used here instead of a new one? Is this the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Agreed. You seem to be using combination of xml and annotations? 'public void setMlService(MLService service) '. Make sure the wiring is done properly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - you'll have to excuse me, I'm very new to Spring and IOC.  The ML Controller class should contain an instance of MLService.  Is passing `mlService()` as an argument to the MLController constructor different than setting it via a setter?

Comment: @BretC is this what you meant? `@Bean
    public MLController mlController(MLService mlService) {
        MLController controller = new MLController();
        controller.setMlService(mlService);
        return controller;
    }`

Comment: I did that, but it didn't fix my build error - do you know anything about the `contextLoads()` test?

Comment: You are really trying very hard to not use Spring Boot... You have a failing test case but happily don't include the testcase. And I highly doubt that that is your full stack trace... Execute the test and add the full stack trace.